# Trouble with Python3 struct pack on a file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have some data
`'BBB', 175, 115, 67`
If I put this data into command like so:

`from struct import pack; open("/home/pi/testfile4", "wb").write(pack("BBB", 175, 115, 67))`

It runs fine, produces the results I expect.

Now if I put that information into a plain text file using nano and run the following commands:
`bin_data = open('/home/pi/file', 'rb').read()`

`from struct import pack; open("/home/pi/testfile4", "wb").write(pack(bin_data))`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

It does not matter if I have 'rb' in the read command for the file. It generates the same error either with or without it.

I am a relative novice when it comes to Python, so I don't know how to do this any other way than the way I am trying. I tried `bytearray` but it didn't produce the results in the format that I expected.

I have attempted this on a Raspberry Pi with Python 3.7.3 and on a Mac with Python 3.8.2 and they both came up with the same error.

What the heck am I doing wrong, and is there another method that will produce the same results?

And if you are wondering what the heck I am doing, I am converting the data over to a format that the Twinkly Christmas lights will accept. So that three bytes of data are to color a single light with RGB color. A 56 light string requires a 168 byte file for a single frame. I am trying to send 24 frames in the same file, so that is a lot of text, Python does not seem like it wants to deal with that much data in a single command, at least from the interpreter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance, you are passing `pack()` the format string `BBB`, and 3 `int`s that can each be stored in an `unsigned char`:

`pack("BBB", 175, 115, 67)`

In the second instance, you are merely passing `pack()` one `str` (the contents read from file, being `'BBB', 175, 115, 67`), which it assumes is the format string.

Be sure to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/struct.html#struct.pack).

You probably want to do something like this:

```py
from struct import pack

with open("/home/pi/lights.txt") as colours_text_file:
    with open("/home/pi/lights.bin", "wb") as colours_bin_file:
        for line in colours_text_file:
            red, green, blue = map(int, line.rstrip().split(", "))
            colours_bin_file.write(pack("BBB", red, green, blue))
```

Where `/home/pi/lights.txt` is a text file with contents like:

```
175, 115, 67
175, 105, 67
175, 95, 67
175, 85, 67
175, 75, 67
175, 65, 67
```

It reads one line at a line, and transforms the `str` to 3 `int`s.

The 3 `int`s are then packed as `unsigned char`s and written to `/home/pi/lights.bin`.